# Hibernate 4.1.0 Final : Initial configuration failing

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-4.x

I am migrating from hibernate 3.0 to 4.1.
I have a code snippet for the initialization of hibernate in my app.

```
        ServiceRegistryBuilder srBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
        srBuilder.configure();
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = srBuilder.buildServiceRegistry();

        // Initializes the session factory.
        sessionConfiguration = new Configuration().configure();
        sessionFactory = sessionConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        sessionSettings = sessionConfiguration.buildSettings(serviceRegistry);
```

I am getting exception at srBuilder.confiugre().
Exception stack trace:
Though the exception says 'timeout', not sure what is this about:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
at org.hibernate.service.internal.JaxbProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbProcessor.java:120)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.JaxbProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbProcessor.java:69)
at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:162)
at org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(ServiceRegistryBuilder.java:147)
at com.vmware.vim.vcenter.das.dao.impl.HibernateUtils.init(HibernateUtils.java:76)
... 24 more
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection timed out: connect]
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.JaxbProcessor.unmarshal(JaxbProcessor.java:108)
... 28 more
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Connection timed out: connect
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwFromIOE(StreamScanner.java:683)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1086)
at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(Unknown Source)
... 31 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your **hibernate.cfg.xml** file

Answer (score 1):

If you are useing Hibernate.cfg.xml,

you can try like this:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
ServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.buildServiceRegistry();
sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```